# How to optimize a regression model without coefficients?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

About myself, I’m very new to machine learning, so I apologize if this question appears incorrect. I have done thorough amount of research into the different (more basic) types of machine learning algorithms, but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direct (or at least let me know if I’m looking in the right field).

I’m trying to optimize a regression model without coefficients (or the least amount of coefficients). Rather, what I am trying to do, is build a regression model that optimizes the way the independent variables are used in the model (i.e uses the fractions of different independent variables, takes the sine of a variable, etc.). The overall goal is to build an accurate model with the least (or no) use of coefficients.

Is there anything out there that does this sort of thing? Any and all feedback is extremely appreciated!

Comment: There are definitely MLAs that don't make any attempt to write down the form of the regression line.  These methods are often high variance and low bias (e.g. Random Forest).  But to specify the form of the regression **and not estimate coefficients** seems difficult.  Do you have a small toy example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes, for sure! I work in materials science/engineering and we try to predict things based on the properties of that material. For example, we would like to predict the number of potholes on a roadway based on the rocks used, type of asphalt/tar, etc. So, the goal would be to develop a regression model without coefficients that could be more universal and based only on the material properties.

Comment: It seems that predicting the # of potholes per lane-mile per mph of speed limit would naturally lead to coefficients, since you'll be wanting to predict it from the regression. A model coefficient is the response-value-per-predictor-value. It is a ratio for continuous predictors (speed limit, max pressure, max temp, max annual temp differential) or a constant for nominal ones: concrete, asphault etc. Predictor values can also be *nonlinear* functions eg $\sqrt{E[mph]}$. You're interested in model selection, which is natural. Model complexity is your  necessary evil; coefficients are blameless.

Comment: @PeterLeopold your comment is both clearly written and correct, yet I have seen people actually blame the coefficients. As I recall, they were usually dancing in intellectual circles at the time.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. Yes, model selection is primarily where the issues arise and correct model selection is key. Do you have any recommendations on how to go about model selection for a mixed continuous and categorical dataset  (I fully realize this is very broad and slight deviation from the OP, so I understand if it cannot be answered)?